# How To Select A Certain Option Field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-selectors, html-select

Jquery is not my main language PHP is.

Anyway,

What I am trying to do is detect if a field has been selected my code almost works but the issue is that when it selects the certain option I get a alert which is good but then when I select the dropdown again [since its being selected] I get another alert which I don't want. What I do want is once the user select the dropdown then clicks the option again I want another alert

```
$('#_privacy_selection').click(function() {

    if($("#_privacy_selection option:selected").text() == 'Certain Users'){
         alert(9);
         return false;
 }

});
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you add a demo/fiddle?

Comment: use change function instead click

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `click` function use `change` function on `<option>`
It will be fired only when you change selected option.

```
$('#_privacy_selection').change(function() {

    if($("#_privacy_selection option:selected").text() == 'Certain Users'){
         alert(9);
         return false;
    }

});
```

Comment: This is close ;)
accept if i clicked the dropdown [no alert which is good] and din't click anything and clicked it again i still get no alert only if i selected something else first but thanks so far :)

Comment: I think this is better behaviour, because you were warned previously. So you do not need to be alerted again when nothing changed.

Comment: Ok might annoy users as what I plan to do is replace the debugging alerts with a dialog box so when the option "Custom" has been selected a dialog box will come up where they can insert more data
[Sort of like the facebook status system]

Comment: I suggest you should define a function: `select_reset(){}` and add something like this command to it: `$('select[id="_privacy_selection"]').val("");` .. Then on `Close` of your dialog, you can call this function which will reset the selected option, and then if the user selects the same option again, `alert(9)` will be fired again as per the if condition. I'm not sure what dialog plugin you're using, but it might have a `onClose` or `Close` option in it's parameters as per the plugin's documentation.